# Dynamically Adding AsyncPostBack Triggers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

In the Page_Load section of my code I am dynamically creating a form. Each row has a save button at the end and I want the form to asynchronously post back when someone clicks the "save" button at the end of a row. I can't seem to achieve this though. I click the button and nothing happens. The click event is not even firing so my guess is that the trigger is not being added properly. Any ideas how I can get this functionality working?

Here is a snippet of my code that I believe is where the problem lies.

```
                Button submit = new Button();
                submit.ID = "Submit_" + reader["SEQN"];
                submit.Text = "Save";
                submit.Click += submitTest; 


                AsyncPostBackTrigger apt = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                apt.ControlID = submit.UniqueID;
                UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(apt);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things i see.  Set the trigger Event to the event you want executed:  apt.EventName = .  The second thing is the id of the button correct after final page rendering.  Check the Buttons id value from web inspector or firebug and see if its the same as what you set for controlid.

Comment: Since I am using buttons the default trigger event is "Click" which is why I left it out. The ID being generated when I view the button through Chrome using inspect element is "ctl00_TemplateBody_WebPartManager1_gwpste_container_eee_cieee_Submit_131308" . I am only registering "Submit_131308". Is their a way to get rid of the preceding junk without hard coding it?

Comment: _EDIT: I tried added that long control name to apt.ControlID and it returned an error saying it could not be found. My guess is that it was finding "Submit_131308" to register, but the event still isn't firing._

Comment: One thing you could try is to set the Button to use a static id by setting the property of ClientIDMode="Static", this will require that the button of course has a unique id for the page.  I use this alot for doing jquery client side work when not using pure class selectors.

Comment: Have you set the EventName to your buttons click event.